# get Array-Object-String thing from the given Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have such an **Object** 
`freq = { a: 50, r: 25, m: 25 }` 
I want to convert it to this **Array-Object** like thing

```
dps = [  
   { label: "a",
     y: 50  },
   { label: "r",
     y: 25  },
   { label: "m",
     y: 25  }
];
```

This is for creating a Chart with canvas.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the entries of the object and take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the key/value pairs and map new objects with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var freq = { a: 50, r: 25, m: 25 },
    dps = Object.entries(freq).map(([label, y]) => ({ label, y }));
    
console.log(dps);
```

Comment: using map() is even better. I was using simple for loop. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: `I was using simple for loop` - well, your loop would be 150ns quicker for each iteration :D if you had code, why not put it in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I think it is the most performant way to do it, because `.map()` is slower than simple `for` loop:

```js
let freq = { a: 50, r: 25, m: 25 } ;
let dps = [];

for (let prop in freq) {
    dps.push({
        label: prop,
        y: freq[prop]
    });
}

console.log(dps);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow method:

```js
var freq = { a: 50, r: 25, m: 25 };
/*
dps = [  
   { label: "a",
     y: 50  },
   { label: "r",
     y: 25  },
   { label: "m",
     y: 25  }
];
*/
var dps = [];
var keys = Object.keys(freq);
keys.map((current,index)=>{
  dps.push({label:keys[index], y:freq[keys[index]]});
});
console.log(dps);
```

Comment: Why would you push in a map and not return anything from map, and discard the mapped result? ... you may as well use forEach

Answer (score -1):

Using for loop and map

```js
//Using for loop for object interation
const freq = { a: 50, r: 25, m: 25 };
var finalFreq=[];
for(let i in freq){
  finalFreq.push({label:i,y:freq[i]});
}
console.log(finalFreq);

//Using map and object keys
var finalFreq=Object.keys(freq).map((freqIndex)=>{
              return {label:freqIndex,y:freq[freqIndex]};
              });
console.log(finalFreq);
```