# Transform Object to array with new keys in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an output from my return Object like the below:

```
{
    "note_1": 14,
    "note_2": 0,
    "note_3": 5,
    "note_4": 17,
    "note_5": 22
}
```

I need to transform this into a new Array where i would need to add values from the above into new keys like the below structure and order reversed

```
[
    {note: 5, count: 22},
    {note: 4, count: 17},
    {note: 3, count: 5},
    {note: 2, count: 0},
    {note: 1, count: 14}
]
```

I have tried to target the last character of the object key to get the note by using the **charAt() function** (dont know if it's the best way to do this!)

```
let distribution = [];

if (props.distribution()) {
    const notes = Object.values(props.distribution).map(item => {
        return item.charAt(item.length-1)
    });
    distribution = Array.from(
        notes.reduce((r, c) => r, new Map()),
        (([note, count]) => ({ note, count }))
    )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `split("_")` in case of a `note_ `> 10?

Comment: in fact it is a rating component, so the note will always be from 1 to 5

Comment: and [get Array-Object-String thing from the given Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607584/get-array-object-string-thing-from-the-given-object) or [How to convert object A to an array of objects with object A's properties and assign value and label to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829402/how-to-convert-object-a-to-an-array-of-objects-with-object-as-properties-and-as)

Comment: as for string manipulation see [Return only text after last underscore in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831974/return-only-text-after-last-underscore-in-javascript-string#:~:text=It's%20very%20simple.,split(%22_%22).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
    "note_1": 14,
    "note_2": 0,
    "note_3": 5,
    "note_4": 17,
    "note_5": 22
}

const transformed = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  const sp = key.split('_');
  const noteVal = sp[1];
  return {
    note: Number(noteVal),
    count: Number(obj[key])
  };
})
console.log(transformed)
```

Comment: arguably `const noteVal = sp.pop()` is more reliable in case there are prior underscores.

Comment: There was also a "reverse" required in the original post

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
const input = {
  note_1: 14,
  note_2: 0,
  note_5: 22,
  note_4: 17,
  note_3: 5,
};

const output = Object.keys(input).map((key) => {
  return { note: key.split('_')[1], value: input[key] };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option to accomplish that. I suggest you to use `slice(-1)` instead of charAt to get the last character.

```
let source = {"note_1":14, "note_2":0, "note_3":5, "note_4":17, "note_5":22 }

Object.entries(source).reverse().map(([k,v])=>({note:k.slice(-1), count:v}))
```

---

Edit:

You can actually use `at(-1)`, it is implemented in practically all relevant browsers now.

```
Object.entries(source).reverse().map(([k,v])=>({note:k.at(-1), count:v}))
```

If your note numbers can grow higher than 10, you'd better `split('_')[1]` and parse to number

```
Object.entries(source).reverse().map(([k,v])=>({note:Number(k.split('_')[1]), count:v}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) where we [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the key to get the everything behind `note_`

```js
const data = {"note_1": 14, "note_2": 0, "note_3": 5, "note_4": 17, "note_5": 22 };

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((p, [ key, value ]) => [ ...p, { 
    note: +key.split("_")[1], 
    count: +value
}], []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    const obj = {
        "note_1": 14,
        "note_2": 0,
        "note_3": 5,
        "note_4": 17,
        "note_5": 22,
    }

    const array = Object.entries(obj).map(arr => {
        return {
            note: +arr[0].charAt(5),
            count: arr[1],
        }
    }).reverse()
```

OUTPUT:

```
0: Object { note: 5, count: 22 }
​
1: Object { note: 4, count: 17 }
​
2: Object { note: 3, count: 5 }
​
3: Object { note: 2, count: 0 }
​
4: Object { note: 1, count: 14 }
```

Answer (score 0):

React JS does need to be mentioned here...
You only need JavaScript

for, Objecet.keys, split methods you need to use for this challenge.